# Should I use XML for data storage on client side?

Tags: xml

I have to create a supplementary program that runs offline on a client machine (normally windows 7 or higher laptop). Of course, I don't want to create a pre-requisite for this program. Since this runs offline, so I can not use a database server either.

This application will store about 500-1000 entry per record and a total of max 100 records.

So, I am trying to decide on the DB tech that works offline, and does not require extra installation on the client's side. Currently I am thinking of using XML to save the data. But I am sure, there are better solutions that I am missing.

Comment: What kind of data is it? Is it relational? Do you need to read it once or more often from disk? Is it modified on disk? Any security considerations? ....?

Answer (score 1):

This also depends on what kind of records you want to be stored, whether it is semi-structured data that is best formed using XML, or plain key-value based records. *SQL Server Express* can store both kinds, but involves an additional install. However, to avoid extra installs, you can check out *SQL Server Compact* and *SQLite*, both of which are installed as a part of the program you will be distributing and will run embedded with it. Also, several NoSQL databases may cure your needs - just give Google a hint and check the answers. Some of them are also compatible with Linq or whatever means you are using to store and extract data from your code.

---

- SQL Server Compact may be downloaded here:
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709
- SQLite
  is available here: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: +1 for SQLite. Imho the right answer for many client-side data storage needs (just look around how many applications use it).

Comment: Thanks. SQLite looks like a good choice, considering it is free to use as well. As for data, it is basically a bunch of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

100 records * 500 to 1000 rows = 50.000 to 100.000

Did you try to estimate the size of the xml file based on the data type of your 'entry'?

If you want to go down the SQL Server road, you can use SQL Server Express. It can be embeded in you installation package.

[Technet: How to Embed SQL Server Express in an Application](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/940.how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application.aspx)

[SQL Server Express: Local Data Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try it, it will prove the best solution for you.
[HTML5 WebSql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

**Adventages:**

1. No Installation Required
2. Store client end data

Comment: [Why is Web SQL database deprecated?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated)

Comment: Its not deprecating in @jitendra case. But its not suitable to store some expensive or critical data at client end, because its data can be cleared by the user by just **Deleting Cookies from web browser**.

Comment: I'm glad I commented, otherwise you might never have mentioned what you just said in your reply to me. How about updating your answer with that information? Seems important enough as a word of caution.